# Fast way to implement a polynomial regression on each pandas dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [11, 12, 31], 1: [6, 14, 27], 2: [11, 24, 21], 3: [1, 24, 20]})

    0   1   2   3
0  11   6  11   1
1  12  14  24  24
2  31  27  21  20
```

For each row at the time, I want to implement a polynomial regression, where column names are X and row values are Y.

I know I can use iterrows:

```
x=(df.columns).to_numpy()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(np.polyfit(x,row,2))
```

which produces:

```
[-1.25  1.25  9.75]
[-0.5  6.1 11.1]
[ 0.75 -6.15 31.35]
```

but this can take a long time on large dataframes.
Is there a faster way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) can take a 2d `y`-param of the same length with `x`, so:

```
np.polyfit(df.columns, df.T, 2).T
```

gives:

```
array([[-1.25,  1.25,  9.75],
       [-0.5 ,  6.1 , 11.1 ],
       [ 0.75, -6.15, 31.35]])
```